# CodeIgniter - Datamapper ORM - Autopopulate Instance

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Just wondering if there is an easy way to auto-populate an object’s related fields on an instance-by-instance basis rather than globally in the config file, or, for the entire class.

I’d like to include all related models for a single instance without chaining a ton of `include_related()` functions.
Something like this would be nice:

```
$x = new Model();
$x->include_all_related();
```

Comment: I don't think DataMapper has any built-in function for that. You could just add the `include_all_related()` function to the model to simply save having to write the code over and over?

Comment: Thanks @froddd - Yeah, that's the approach I'm taking now - but it means when I create a new model and fill out it's relationships (`$has_many()` and `$has_one()`), I also have to head into the `include_all_related()` function and make adjustments there too. I've asked it on [DMORM CI Forum](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/205637/P825) too. Our solution is a temporary fix, when I'm less busy, and provided I don't get an answer, I'll dig into the core and create a method myself :D

Comment: Actually, I don't have to keep changing the `include_all_related()` function if I just read in the `$has_one` or `$has_many` arrays. _facepalm_. See solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd have to get my hands dirty in the core. For whatever reason, it didn't occur to me that I could access the `$has_many` and `$has_one` arrays.

Solution was simple:

```
class Model extends Datamapper{
    var $has_one = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
    var $table = 'models';

    function __construct($id = NULL){
        parent::__construct($id);
    }

    function include_all_related(){
        foreach($this->has_one as $h){
            $this->include_related($h['class']);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

You might wonder why I'm using the `class` key in the `$h` variable. Under the hood, Datamapper ORM keeps track of some other keys too as part of a bigger array. If you call `print_r($h)`, you can see them. The `class` key keeps track of `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it on the relation definition, if you want is on a particular instance, you need to change the relation configuration of that instance at runtime.